# Maximum-security batch size in Keras Sequential model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, sequential, batchsize

I'm training a Keras Sequential model where I haven't specified a `batch_size`. When I took a look into a list which is saving all my batch sizes during training, I observed that 1200 seemed like the maximum batch size.

My input data has 1500 samples. When I specify the batch size to 1500, keras is still splitting this into 1200 and an extra 300. When I do not specify something, I get 37 times 32 batches plus one of size 16 (=1200) and then 9 times 32 plus one with size 12 (=300). Saved batch size:

[image]

I looked into the keras Sequential model documentation [here](https://keras.io/models/sequential/), but haven't found an explanation why this is happening.

I thought about if maybe my memory is too small for 1500 samples, but during calculations it's only used about 60%. And this is no explanation for the second observation.

Comment: Maybe it’s taking 80% by 20% like 80% train 20% test

Comment: I'm asking myself how I could not see that. You're right that's the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is because by default it takes 80% of the data to train with it and 20% of the data to test with it.